# how to call a child component from parent component in electron-es6-react

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am using electron-es6-react when i am trying to call achild component from parent component it not working can any one help me,here is the sample what i have done,

```
   export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            result: [{"name":hhhh","date":"12-05-2015"}];
    }
    }
    render(){
    return(
     <fixedTable result={this.state.result}/>
    )
    }
}

class fixedTable extends React.Component{
render(){
alert("child);
return(
<div>hai</div>
)
}
}
```

any help must be appreciated

Comment: What's up with `alert("child)` do you mean to `alert(this.props.result)`?

Comment: yah exactly i need to use the result data in the child component,for that i am checking that child component is working or not ,but the child component alert is not coming

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your `fixedTable` component inside the scope of your `Main` class :

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            result: [{"name":hhhh,"date":"12-05-2015"],
        };
        class fixedTable extends React.Component{
            render(){
                 alert("child);
                 return(
                     <div>hai</div>
                 )
            }
         }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <fixedTable result={this.state.result}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response when i am calling child component from the parent,not getting the response from the child

Comment: No i didn't get any error,and the child component is also not called,in the child component the alert is not coming

Answer (score 1):

The name of you react Component must begin with an upper case character. Thats the reason you child component doesn't get called. Also apart from this you need to correct several typing mistakes in your code and do not include a `;` inside the state declaration

```js
 class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            result: [{"name":"hhhh","date":"12-05-2015"}]
    }
    }
    render(){
    return(
     <FixedTable result={this.state.result}/>
    )
    }
}

class FixedTable extends React.Component{
render(){
alert("child");
return(
<div>hai</div>
)
}
}
                     
ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```